# Error checking SSLError the certificate through a proxy, telegram bot, corporate network

Tags: python, proxy, bots, telegram-bot

I work through a corporate network, there is a need to write a bot telegram, I tried various libraries (`` telebot, telepot, telegram, airogram ''). Everywhere I come across the problem of access through a corporate proxy. Now I stopped at telebot, slipped a proxy, now there is an error with certificate verification. Tried using http, https, socks5, socks5h, socks4 with no success.

```
import telebot
import json
from telebot import apihelper

with open ('params.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load (f)
username = data ['username']
password = data ['password']
access_token_tg = data ['access_token_tg']
bot = telebot.TeleBot (access_token_tg)
apihelper.proxy = {'https': f'https: // {username}: {password} @ 10.0.18.139: 3131'}
print (bot.get_me ())
```

I get an error in response.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool (host = 'api.telegram.org', port = 443): Max retries exceeded with url: / my token here / getMe (Caused by SSLError (SSLCertVerificationError (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c: 1123) ')))
```

I tried to communicate via request with the cart, I was able to connect, only after disabling the ssl check `` session.verify = False ''. But it is very problematic to write through requests, in fact, there are a lot of libraries for this.

```
import pprint
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
import urllib3
import requests
import json

# read config
with open ('params.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load (f)
username = data ['username']
password = data ['password']
access_token_tg = data ['access_token_tg']

# create a session to work with the bot
auth = HTTPProxyAuth (username, password)
proxies = {'https': f'https: // {username}: {password} @ 10.0.18.139: 3131'}
session = requests.Session ()
session.proxies = proxies
session.auth = auth

# chopped off the verification of the certificate and warning
urllib3.disable_warnings ()
session.verify = False

MAIN_URL = f'https: //api.telegram.org/bot {access_token_tg} '
res = session.post (f '{MAIN_URL} / getMe'). json ()
pprint.pprint (res)
This is how it works.

I ask you to help me figure it out, or maybe I can advise another manual or bibla, I have been fighting with this for 2 weeks.
```